# Symfony - persisting array in string field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

In my Symofny project while persisting an entity, I am passing my user roles via request and when dumping that roles, structure looks like:

[roles dump img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D0MF.png)

Filed I am persisting it in, (not in user table) is for some mixed values and it's type of **string** as I am using it for mixed purposes.
So, when persisting I always get:

> **Notice: Array to string conversion**

I found a lot of questions but non of them works for me:

I treid:

```
$new->setValue(json_encode(json_decode($roles)));
```

and

```
$new->setValue(implode(',', $roles));
```

Always getting the same error. Can someone offer an alternative so I can persist roles into string filed and surpass this error?

Comment: Hello !
You can use an event listener on the "prepersist" and "preupdate" events. You can find information about that here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html

Comment: How is the entity mapped? Can you paste the code here?

Comment: Use [simple array](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#simple-array) doctrine field type.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the JSON encoding is done by Doctrine. Usually, I set roles like this:

```
public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

public function addRole(string $role): self
{
    $this->roles[] = $role;

    return $this;
}
```